# Enabling button if there is at least one checked item in ListCheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to do a Form where the user has to click at least one option of the ones given on the ListCheckBox in order to enable a sort of "Next" button.

However, its not working as expected since, sometimes, the button is enabled while there is no option chosen.

This is the code of the class where I do the validations:

```
class CampoCheckedListBox : AbstractCampo
{
    private CheckedListBox checkedListBox { get; set; }
    private string nombre { get; set; }
    private bool obligatorio { get; set; }

    public CampoCheckedListBox(string nom, CheckedListBox controller, bool oblig)
    {
        this.checkedListBox = controller;
        this.nombre = nom;
        this.obligatorio = oblig;
    }

    public override void validar()
    {
        string mensaje = "";

        if (this.obligatorio && checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count==0)
        {
            mensaje += "-Seleccione al menos una de las opciones de " + this.nombre + "." + Environment.NewLine;
            throw new ValidationException(mensaje);
        }

    }
}
```

In my form:

```
    private void validarCampos()
    {
        List<AbstractCampo> campos = new List<AbstractCampo>();
        campos.Add(new Campo("Nombre", tBoxRol.Text, true, Controller.TipoValidacion.Alfanumerico));
        campos.Add(new CampoCheckedListBox("Funcionalidades", chkBoxFuncionalidades, true));
        try
        {
            Controller.validarCampos(campos);
            darAlta_button.Enabled = true;
            errorBox.Text = "";
        }
        catch (ValidationException vEx)
        {
            errorBox.Text = vEx.mensaje;
            darAlta_button.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Controller.validarCampos() just takes each object from a list and send message validar();
And I call this validarCampos() in the SelectedIndexChanged event on the ListCheckBox.

There are sometimes that I check an option and the button isnt enabled. But if I uncheck the same option and then check it again the button gets enabled.

I am pretty lost here...

Comment: do you check button.enable in  index change event?because even when you uncheck the index event gets raised

Comment: Where could you find the control `ListCheckBox`? Do you mean it `CheckedListBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event instead of the SelectedIndexChanged event. The CheckedListBox uses CheckedItems and CheckedIndices in addition to the inherited SelectedItems and SelectedIndices so there is probably a disconnect between the 2 types and the events that are fired.

Comment: it still fires on uncheck mufaka

Answer (score 0):

`Controller.validarCampos()` is to validate more then one **AbstractCampo** objects. Exception will be thrown and button will be disabled if there are no checked items in the first **AbstractCompo** object which I believe is not what you want.

The logic is a bit wrong here, you should use bool return value for `Validar()` and `Controller.validarCampos()` should throw exception if `Validar()` return **false** for all items in **campos**.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Like Mufaka said, you should probably be doing this inside a handler for the ItemCheck event instead of SelectedIndexChanged. (It might be possible to check/uncheck a box without selecting the item, but I'm not sure).
2. You have used the following in one of your conditions:

   > checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count==0

   In reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx), there are actually three states a box can be in:

   - Checked
   - Unchecked
   - Indeterminate

   But the CheckedItems property will return the collection of items that are Checked **or Indeterminate**, so if your checkboxes start in the indeterminate/default state this might not be the count that you want.

---

edit: You can check as follows:

```
bool isAnyChecked = false; 
foreach( var index in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices ) 
{ 
  if( checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState( index ) == CheckState.Checked ) 
  { 
    isAnyChecked = true; 
    break; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: how could i know if a field is indetermidate?